# Nginx custom html folder

Tags: ubuntu, go, nginx

I'm new to nginx server and have some trouble. Im trying to server a static file but it is only working if i place it in:
/var/www/html

I would like to place my index.html in this folder:
/home/bowa/go/go-web/frontend

This is my server config:

```
server {
    server_name braurl.se www.braurl.se;

    root /home/bowa/go/go-web/frontend/;
    index.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9990;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/braurl.se/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/braurl.se/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

This is my golang code to serve the file:

(my main.go is located in the folder: /home/bowa/go/go-web/ )

```
func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "/frontend/index.html")
}
```

The only way i succeed in serving index.html is if i define no root in my server config and
if i change my go code like this:

```
http.ServeFile(w, r, "/var/www/html/index.html")
```

This is driving me a little crazy and i would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

I got this working in localhost but not on nginx.

```
func serveFiles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.URL.Path)
    p := "." + r.URL.Path
    if p == "./" {
        p = "./frontend/index.html"
    }
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    api := r.PathPrefix("/api/v1").Subrouter()

    // index.html
    r.HandleFunc("/", serveFiles)
}
```

Structure: 
[Pic of server structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APxpx.png)

Comment: Are you trying to serve the file with your Go app or with Nginx?

Comment: I would prefer to serve it with Go app, in the future i will use react as front-end and i think it will make my life easier to server the react prod build files with Go

Comment: If you're serving it with Go then you don't need `root` configured in Nginx because Nginx isn't serving any files, it's just acting as a proxy. And the paths in your Go code will need to be whatever is the correct path to the files you want to serve, bearing in mind that relative paths will be relative to the working path of the executing program.

Comment: Thank you, what your saying is making sence
The correct path would me frontend/index.html in my Go code, it stills gives me a 404 tho, strange
- Maybe i need to disable nginx serve more than removing root?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct path in your Go code? Are you running the program from  /home/bowa/go/go-web/?

Comment: Also in your quoted code you have `"/frontend/index.html"` which isn't the same thing as `"frontend/index.html"`

Comment: I updated what Ive done now in my code. Yes the main.go file is located at: /home/bowa/go/go-web/
Ive made a folder called frontend and placed index.html there. Its working localhost but not on my nginx, it still throws a 404.

Comment: agree with Adrian, that first you should decide who will serve index.html: nginx or golang
here is example for go version (also with https, if needed uncomment)


`    func main() {
 http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/home/bowa/go/go-web") ) )

 //err := http.ListenAndServeTLS( ":443",
 // "/etc/letsencrypt/live/braurl.se/fullchain.pem",
 // "/etc/letsencrypt/live/braurl.se/privkey.pem",
 // nil)

 err := http.ListenAndServe( ":8081", nil)

 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }
    }`

`curl -v "http://localhost:8081/frontend/index.html"`